# Adding variables to page--taxonomy.tpl.php

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How do I add preprocess variables to `page--taxonomy.tpl.php` which will be available only to the vocabulary *Project Type*? I know my code below is wrong.

```
function themename_preprocess_taxonomy(&$vars, $hook){
    $vars['testing'] = 'It works!'; // This doesn't work :p

    // If that checks out, how to limit it only to a specific vocabulary (e.g. Shoes)?
}
```

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right template file? The Taxonomy term uses [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7).

Comment: Oh, you're right. I think I may be using the wrong template file.

Comment: You should also make clear what you mean by _vocabulary Project Type_ as vocabularies are not project types, in Drupal.

Comment: *Project Type* is the name of the vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit variables to certain conditions. Obviously only when the variables to measure these conditions are available.

```
function themename_preprocess_taxonomy(&$vars, $hook){
  var_dump($vars);
}
```

This will show you all the available variables, for example the $vid, which contains the vocabulary-ID. The simple version would be:

```
function themename_preprocess_taxonomy(&$vars, $hook){
  if($vars['vid'] == 12) {
    $vars['example'] = "Foo";
  }
}
```

A clean, and much better solution would then be:

```
function themename_preprocess_taxonomy(&$vars, $hook){
  $vars['example'] = ''; # Always instantiate a variable, and make sure
                          # it has a constant type 
                          # e.g. always return a string.
  if($vars['vid'] == variable_get('themename_vid_for_example', 123)) { # Avoid Magic Numbers [1]
    $vars['example'] = "Foo";
  }
}
```

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants

**EDIT:** updated variable_get. tss.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `variable_get()` without arguments?

Comment: That was a mistake. Sorry, fixed!